# How can i programmatically post an update to my status on Google+

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm currently looking at using the Google+ API for Android. I cannot glean how to post an update to my status on Google+

Answer (score 5):

You cannot glean it because the API does not support it. The [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/) is read only.

Comment: Is this still the case? Have they enabled posting or is it still read only?

Comment: If you look at the API link you will see there is the concept of posting a "moment". That appears to be the only writeable resource.